# Regex to ignore data between different types of brackets

Tags: regex

Let's say I've got the following text

```
search [search](search) search) (search)
```

I just want to ignore every match between a leading square bracket and the first closing round bracket.

I thought I could just use a negative lookahead for anything inbetween, but my Regex doesn't work, as it only begins highlighting again after the last closed round bracket. Any ideas?

```
search(?![\[\])])
```

Comment: Please _edit_ your question, and fix your input text by removing the text which you have added, but which is NOT part of the real text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negated character class looking for `^\)`.
We look for square brackets, and search any character which is not a `)` and add `\)` at the end to find the closing `)`:

```regex
(\[[^\)]+\))
```

This finds: `[search](search)`

Using capture groups you can remove these from the result programmatically.
Otherwise I believe you will have to parse the string instead of using one regex.

```regex
([^\[]+)(\[[^\)]+\))(.+)
```

`$1$3` will be your new string.

Comment: Thank you. This already helps, but I'm not sure how to to find everything but `[search](search)`, so the exact opposite.

Comment: I have made an addition to the answer. You can get more complicated with negative lookahead but you will have to give exact details in your question.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I might have explained myself wrong. I want to find every instance of "search" in the provided string, with the exception of instances between a leading square bracket and a closing round bracket. The actual string is much longer than the given example, so the solution needs to be infinitely applicable. A similar use case is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694542/regex-ignore-between-brackets-and-parentheses
The provided solution doesn't work for my use case, however, since I don't want to remove them from my string, just skip them in the search.

Comment: That is hard (maybe impossible) to do with just regex... the closest I have gotten is `(?<!\[)(search(?!=\]\[^\)]+))` which will still find the `search` in round brackets after the `[search]` one. The more complicated regex get the more processing they actually need - it's sometimes efficient and more readable to do part of the task programmatically.

Comment: I see, that's what I feared. Thanks for the help.